# Is is necessary to do apt-get update everytime

Tags: apt, debian

I wonder if in debian flavours you should always do a update before 
apt-get install?

What are the disadvantages if I just install without updating?

Comment: the packages in the repo may be updated even today itself also. So to get the updated latest version of package, you have to update the repos before installing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a best practice.  There's an update daemon that checks on a schedule, at least if you configure it to do so, so the odds are you're "probably" going to get the latest version if you don't manually run apt-get update .  However, it's a best practice to do apt-get update first just to make sure that your package manager is aware of all of the software versions currently available in the repos.  Canonical is not like Microsoft, they don't publish updates only on certain days, at least that I'm aware of, so there could have been a new version of something uploaded at any moment, so it's always a good idea to do an apt-get update first to make sure your package manager is aware of that.